# Load balance method based on memory availability

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

Is it possible to load balance ingress traffic based on the resource availability on the pods?  The closest I can find is [Nginx's Least Time load balance method](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#least_time) which uses lowest average latency.

I'm specifically looking for a way to route to the pod with the most average memory availability.

Comment: I don't know of any ingress that would do that. Although in theory, this might be doable - coding your own ingress, that would query your cluster metrics.

Comment: Hi, it doesn't seem to be recommended: https://serverfault.com/questions/400899/why-dont-load-balancer-algorithms-allow-selection-of-worker-machines-based-on/400939 and https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/dahlin/papers/tpds-loadBalance00.pdf

Answer (score 1):

This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.

As already mentioned in the comments, that approach is not recommended as the main issues with resource based load balancing is that the load information becomes stale by the time you would make the routing decision. See the sources below:

- [Why don't load balancer algorithm's allow selection of worker machines based on current CPU or memory usage](https://serverfault.com/questions/400899/why-dont-load-balancer-algorithms-allow-selection-of-worker-machines-based-on/400939)
- [Interpreting Stale Load Information](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/dahlin/papers/tpds-loadBalance00.pdf)